# null is not an object(evaluating this.state.count)

Tags: react-native

I am facing the above mentioned error when i am trying to set a count for everytime the button is pressed.

```
export default class ViewIdeas extends Component{
get InitialState(){
  return {
  count : 0
  }
}
render(){
    return(
   .......
 <Button transparent>
             <Icon name='ios-thumbs-up-outline' style={{fontSize:21}} 
              onPress={() => this.setState({count: ++this.state.count})}/>
              <Text>{'Like' + this.state.count}</Text>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Error is saying that either this is null, or this.state is null

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please set state like this

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {
      count: 0,
   }
}
```

And then you can do this.state.count

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to make a React class : ES6 and by using React.createClass.

The two approaches are not interchangeable. You should initialize state in the constructor when using ES6 classes, and define the `getInitialState` method when using `React.createClass`.

[See the official React doc on the subject of ES6 classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { /* initial state */ };
  } // Note that there is no comma after the method completion
}
```

is equivalent to

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { /* initial state */ };
  },
});
```

Also one more thing to note would be there are no commas after the constructor method.